# How do I get Blender to import a Collada file?

Tags: import, collada

Collada is not among the import options, and not among the addons for import options.

So is there a way to import a Collada file to Blender?

Comment: Collada is a `.dae` file and as you can see here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6OUPH.png (blender 2.73a) it is supported.

Comment: Hey Luke, we DO read the differences and its you not getting it. Probably the answers in the duplicate are not clear enough for some people, might be actually good idea to answer about import also here. The thing is export and import are tied together, and the answers in the duplicate say to get a newer version which solves the issue.

Comment: For every other format Blender has support for, there is more than likely an import as well as export option. While the title differs, the answer would have still been the same more or less. Regardless, I think this should have its own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use File-Import-Collada (Default)(.dae).

[image]

Comment: Add that it should be a modern version since that was op's problem.

Comment: @iKlsR feel free to edit.

Comment: Cool. I suspected the reason my question was flagged as a duplicate had to do precisely with the fact that an answer to the other question might also be an answer to MY question. However, that makes the label "duplicate" rather dubious. Perhaps the forum design and programming could be modified to have a better label for this situation. Rather than labeling different questions that are both answered by a comment on one of them as "duplicate questions," maybe we can call such questions "Different questions answered by a comment on one but not both of the questions." Or some shorter version.