# Collada Import in 2.76

Tags: collada

Just got blender and was going to get started trying my hand on some .dae files, however after trying several times to import them, nothing seems to happen. I get nothing. Am I doing something wrong, some settings need to be in place before doing a file>import>collada?

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/how-do-i-get-blender-to-import-a-collada-file

Comment: I have the option to import, it simply is not doing anything when I try and import. No error, nothing on stage, just nothing happens. I have tired a number of different .dae's but still nothing.

Comment: I just imported this in my 2.76 just fine 
http://www.3dvia.com/models/11F53407192B3D0F/fauteuil-flax

Comment: Is there anything in you scene hierarchy? I have issues with some Collada files. I checked that the schema is valid, and I can open them with other viewers, but Blender doesn't show anything on stage. There are new objects imported in the scene hierarchy, though, but when I click on any of the geometry, Blender just crashes.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the geometry content of your DAE file is a type that the Blender importer does not understand.  I was trying to read in Collada files that were made from **triangle strips** and I got the same result.  No error message, no visible geometry, no objects in the scene tree.  The files passed the consistency checker with no errors.  These were files I was generating myself, so I was able to change the geometry from **triangle strips** to **triangles** and it worked fine.  I am using an older version of Blender, 2.69.

When I searched for information on Blender importing Collada triangle strips I found old reports of the importer not working, but no recent reports on working/not working.