# No Collada (.dae) Import option on Ubuntu 2.76b

Tags: import, collada

I'm running blender on Ubuntu 16.04, with just a simple `apt-get install blender` and the blender version is 2.76b. When I goto File->Import there is no option to import .dae files. Is there anyway around this, reinstalling, using a repository or manually adding in an add-on that could help fix this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add the ability to import Collada files to Blender 2.76?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57486/how-do-i-add-the-ability-to-import-collada-files-to-blender-2-76)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/how-do-i-get-blender-to-import-a-collada-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix (by complete coincidence) on this Github page: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Chromebook-Pixel

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt update && sudo apt install blender
```